# Using table mapping in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm having lots of difficulty trying to use Entity Framework 6 for a simple application. I used the "EF Designer From Database" option, and something's wrong with my data model or my object model but I can't figure it out. I can't post images yet, but here is the SQL for my data model:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Company] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Phone] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Feature](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Type] [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Feature] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[License](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Comment] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NULL,
    [ExpirationDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [SerialNumber] [char](26) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_License] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LicenseItem](
    [LicenseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Seats] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LicenseItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LicenseID] ASC, [ItemID] ASC)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PackageModule](
    [PackageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModuleID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PackageModule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PackageID] ASC, [ModuleID] ASC)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[License]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_License_Customer] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[License] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_License_Customer]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LicenseItem]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LicenseItem_Feature] FOREIGN KEY([ItemID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Feature] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LicenseItem] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LicenseItem_Feature]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LicenseItem]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LicenseItem_License] FOREIGN KEY([LicenseID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[License] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LicenseItem] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LicenseItem_License]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PackageModule]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageModule_ModuleID_Feature] FOREIGN KEY([ModuleID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Feature] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PackageModule] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageModule_ModuleID_Feature]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PackageModule]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageModule_PackageID_Feature] FOREIGN KEY([PackageID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Feature] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PackageModule] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageModule_PackageID_Feature]
GO
```

For my object model, I made `Feature` an abstract class and created `Package` and `Module` entities that inherit from `Feature` (feature is mapped to both `Package` and `Module` using `Type` as a discriminator). `Package` and `Module` are associated together with a many-to-many relationship, which is mapped to the `PackageModule` table, and I associated those to `License` so that `License` has `Packages` and `Modules` collections (with FK constraints). Here's where I'm stuck:

I added a `Seats` property to both `Package` and `Module`, deleted the auto-generated `LicenseItem` entity, and mapped `LicenseItem` to the `Package` and `Module` entities to map the `Seats` property to. This fails because the `LicenseID` PK is not mapped, and I just can't figure out how to get around this. I'm obviously missing something fundamental, so...be gentle. :)

Comment: if `LicenceItem` is something that all classes inheriting from `Feature` use, you should be able to add it as a property on the `Feature` class?  But I'm not sure I see where they are mapped in the SQL?

Comment: When you say EF Designer From Database do you mean database first? If so what do you mean by you made classes..., they would be generated for you by EF?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I think what I keep running into is needing to have entities mapped to multiple tables, and having to map key properties is bothering me. This is my core problem: my company's licenses contain modules and/or groups of modules (packages), with a number of seats assigned to each module or package. So I have to store the available modules & packages separately from those assigned to a license. To track a license's modules I could have a `LicenseModule` table with a Seats column, but how would I map the Module entity to the Module and LicenseModule tables and map all the PKs?